# Crystal Reports for VB6 install issue - ordinal could not be located in CRPE32.ddl

Tags: vb6

When I install Crystal Reports installer for VB6, CRYSTL32.EXE, I am getting an error saying,

> The ordinal 1132 could not be located in the dynamic link library CRPE32.dll

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Installing VB 6, CRYSTL32.EXE on a machine without .NET did not create this error.